# In simple terms, When do we use service and when do we use directives in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there have been many answers. 
But still, i cannot understand when to use them both.

A Service is an object that can be reused within an angular application.

A Directive lets you extend HTML with new attributes.

When do we know that now we have to use service and now directive?

Comment: use directives for DOM manipulation (since it has jQLite and can compile templates, etc. Use Services to share data between controllers (and, therefore, between pages). Directives will lose data once you redirect the page. Services lose the data once you refresh the page.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thank you. Really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having two sub-pages in your web application. Both pages use e.g. the fictive directive `my-counter` that displays a counter that is increased whenever the directive is instantiated.

Whenever you switch between those pages, the counter on the current page is destroyed and the counter on the page you are switching to is instantiaded. You would only ever see the counter displaying `1` (or `0` depending on when you increase it).

Services survive page-switching. They are ideally only instantiated once and can keep track of overall/global state.

So if instead of keeping the count within the directive, but instead injecting the service into the directive and incrementing the counter in the service, your counter would go up everytime you switch the page.